# Bitwise XOR operator not working in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword, xor

I am trying to do this :

**print 17593028247552 ^ 909522486**

The result must be **67450422**(as is in javascript) but I am getting **17592253494838L**

Please help me ! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2's `long` type (or `int` in Python 3) can grow as large as they need to, but it looks like you want a 32 bit result.

You just need to mask the result so you only get the low 32 bits of the result. And I guess that since you're on Python 2 you should also convert it from `long` to `int`.

```
>>> int((17593028247552 ^ 909522486 ) & 0xffffffff)
67450422
```

Comment: I might be tempted to put it as `2 ** 32 - 1` to make it a bit more obvious as to the number of bits the result is being rounded to (and a quick change if you wanted to round it to 64 for instance...)

Comment: @Jon Fair enough. Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but I like the hex form. :) OTOH, Python will evaluate `2 ** 32 - 1` when it compiles the script, so there's no real advantage in using the hex form.

Comment: I also happen to like the hex-form - I just wouldn't want to type it for 128 bits :) (I'd probably get it wrong for a start...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped

Answer (score 0):

I just used Windows calculator:

```
100000000000000110010001100110000000000000000  = 17593028247552d
000000000000000110110001101100011011000110110  =      909522486d
100000000000000000100000001010011011000110110  = 17592253494838d
```

Looks like JavaScript is wrong. It's probably narrowing to 32 bit or something before doing XOR. Python is arbitrary precision on integers.

Edit: As the other answer points out, if you're still using Python 2 (don't do that!) only long is arbitrary precision; the precision of int can vary but it's usually 64 bit. In Python 3 there is only one integer type and it's always arbitrary precision.

Comment: Python can be 32 bit or 64 bit. Some of us are still running 32 bit machines... In a 32 bit build, Python 2 `int` is 32 bit.